# Multiple page printing

Tags: c#-4.0, printing

Can any one suggest me which one is the best way for printing multiple document, in windows form c# application?
I am be able to print single document but become afraid when its come multiple documents...

Comment: What happens if you send prints for the documents one by one ?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578005/document-printing-not-give-proper-output I am having same type of problem, and I m so afraid, god help me from this code.....
:(